# Font-lock Yasnippet template from within Org-Babel block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, font-lock, yasnippet

I want to manage my library of snippets from a single `org-mode` document and tangle these to their respective snippet files, as needed. Now functionally, this works out-of-the box, with the one exception: `org-babel` does not know how to font-lock a snippet and I cannot find an `ob-snippet.el` file anywhere on the web.

Now Yasnippet does has a `snippet` major mode that it uses to font-locks snippets, when viewed from their own buffer. How can I get `org-babel` to use this to fontify snippets from within a babel code block?

To better illustrate, here is a screenshot of my `article` snippet from within `org-mode`

[image]
and here it is, nice and fontified under the `snippet` major mode:

[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't use images for code: you make life difficult for potential answerers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source code block has `text` set as the mode.  Try changing that to read

`#+BEGIN_SRC snippet :tangle ~/org/snippets/bibtex-mode/article`

[image]

Comment: That did it. Thanks @gregoryg!